# Передача параметров в контроллер JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Каким образом можно передать параметр в контроллер из Application в методе start?

метод start:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("windows/userTestWindow.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();

    UserTestController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setStage(primaryStage);

    primaryStage.setTitle("TESTOsteron - Тест");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(MIN_WIDTH);
    primaryStage.setMinHeight(MIN_HEIGHT);
    primaryStage.getIcons().add(icon);

    //controller.setTestKod(testKod);

    primaryStage.show();
}
```

пробовал передать через

```
 controller.setTestKod(testKod);
```

то есть в контроллере имеется такой метод и поле testKod, но ничего не передается, testKod по прежнему 0. я просто не понимаю почему тогда Stage передается таким образом в контроллер, а простой параметр не может.

Comment: Может быть проблема в том, что ты testKod не апдейтишь? По твоему все должно быть правильно. Только не понятно, зачем ты в контроллер primaryStage пихаешь

Comment: чтобы из контроллера можно было управлять сценой

Comment: @AndrewBystrov ты оказался прав. нужно было переинициализировать FXML после изменения параметра. Так все сработало